# MySQL Trigger If Statement with Comparison from Query

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I could use a little guidance with trigger in a 5.6 MySQL environment. I would like to create a trigger that stops an update if a lower price is found for a pc with the same speed.

The schema is 
Product (**maker**, **model**, type)
PC (**model**, speed, ram, hdisk, price)
Laptop (**model**, speed, ram, hdisk, screen, price)
Printer (**model**, color, type, price)

bold is primary key.

My best attempt is

```
delimiter //
create trigger trigger2 before update on pc
for each row 
begin
    if (new.price < (min(price) from pc where speed=new.speed))
then signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'lower price found';
   end if;
end;//
delimiter ;
```

but I actually get a syntax error about the if condition.
http://rextester.com/TJT52527 here is a sample dataset.
Any guidance is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the trigger with the correct syntax:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trigger2 BEFORE UPDATE ON pc FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF (NEW.price < (SELECT MIN(price) FROM pc WHERE speed = NEW.speed)) THEN
       signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'lower price found';
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Demonstration:

Update with a higher price works:

```
mysql> UPDATE pc SET price = 2000 WHERE speed = 2.20;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0
```

Update with a lower price fails:

```
mysql> UPDATE pc SET price = 200 WHERE speed = 2.20;
ERROR 1644 (45000): lower price found
mysql>
```

PS: thanks a lot for the SQL schema, it helps greatly

Comment: Thank you very much, sometimes I am dense motherf***** because I was just missing a select, haha. Thanks again.